# style not apply in print page using javascript

Tags: javascript, printing, printing-web-page

Am using the below code to print the ASPX web page.It's working. But the style sheet not apply for this template.please help me to apply the style for print page.

```
 <script language="javascript">
        function printpr() {

            var panel = document.getElementById("<%= all.ClientID %>");
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="print"/>\n')
            printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
            printWindow.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                printWindow.print();
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think this should be able to guide you through your problem.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmedia.shtml